# Issue with Tabbed Widget active class

Tags: jquery, css

I have created two tabs called tab1 and tab2. While hovering on tab1 or tab2, the corresponding details of tab1 and tab2 will display. And it was working like a charm. The code for this one is,

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="active"><b>Tab1</b></li>
        <li class=""><b>Tab2</b></li> 
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-container">
    <div class="tab-content" style="display: none; opacity: 1;">     
        Tab1
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" style="display: none; opacity: 1;">     
        Tab2
    </div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.tab-content:eq(0)').show();
$('#tab1').show();
$('ul.tabs li').mouseover(function() {
var i = $(this).index();
$('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
$('.tab-content').hide();
$('.tab-content').eq(i).fadeTo(300,1);
return false;
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

For tab1 and tab 2, i use small css to differentiate them, the css is shown below,

```
.tabs{
overflow:hidden;    
}

.tabs li{
list-style: none;
float: left;
padding: 7px 36px;
background: #D2161E;
color: #fff;
cursor:pointer; 
}

.tabs li.active{
background:#000;    
}
```

Ok when i refresh the site which i included this jquery tab, the two tab1 and tab2 is showing the same color `#D2161E`. How to differentiate the class name `.active` color by default for tab1

Comment: If you want to create multiple tab then try this:http://codepen.io/hamzadhamiya/pen/esKCD

Comment: @MohammedHâmzã Thanks for your reply, but I just need to hover on the tab, so that it should show the details. Not by clicking the tab what you have mentioned. Could you please try the above one, so that you could know what is my issue.

Comment: But their isn't any problem in the script it works correctly. When I refresh the page the tab1 have black #000 background which I think is correct.